# How to clear the cache for specific NetworkImageView with Volley?

Tags: android, caching, android-volley, networkimageview

I have an NetworkImageView in my app and the link in the database changes every five seconds so i have to remove the cache to refresh image. I tried this code but it does not remove the cache.

```
VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(IMAGE_URL);

mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);
mImageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader();
mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);
```

Comment: Pls read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755109/disable-or-remove-cache-in-networkimageview-volley/34757041#34757041

Comment: @BNK thank u so much, could u check my question under the answer which is in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734999/android-volley-image-caching-questions/34736194#34736194 also, is the answer that he gave in the third part good method? thank you

Comment: About #3 in his answer, as you find in my answer, no hack, and no header, you can check more in Volley classes relating to NetworkImageView such as ImageLoader...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code inside `VolleySingleton` class:

```
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        }
});
```

You can check when debugging, set breakpoint at following line

`Bitmap cachedBitmap = mCache.getBitmap(cacheKey);`

inside `ImageLoader.java`, you will find `cachedBitmap` null.

OR put `Log.w("cachedBitmap", "Bitmap cached!");` as my following code to check:

```
public ImageContainer get(String requestUrl, ImageListener imageListener,
    int maxWidth, int maxHeight, ScaleType scaleType) {

// only fulfill requests that were initiated from the main thread.
throwIfNotOnMainThread();

final String cacheKey = getCacheKey(requestUrl, maxWidth, maxHeight, scaleType);

// Try to look up the request in the cache of remote images.
Bitmap cachedBitmap = mCache.getBitmap(cacheKey);
if (cachedBitmap != null) {
    Log.w("cachedBitmap", "Bitmap cached!");
    // Return the cached bitmap.
    ImageContainer container = new ImageContainer(cachedBitmap, requestUrl, null, null);
    imageListener.onResponse(container, true);
    return container;
}

// The bitmap did not exist in the cache, fetch it!
ImageContainer imageContainer =
        new ImageContainer(null, requestUrl, cacheKey, imageListener);

// Update the caller to let them know that they should use the default bitmap.
imageListener.onResponse(imageContainer, true);

// Check to see if a request is already in-flight.
BatchedImageRequest request = mInFlightRequests.get(cacheKey);
if (request != null) {
    // If it is, add this request to the list of listeners.
    request.addContainer(imageContainer);
    return imageContainer;
}

// The request is not already in flight. Send the new request to the network and
// track it.
Request<Bitmap> newRequest = makeImageRequest(requestUrl, maxWidth, maxHeight, scaleType,
        cacheKey);

mRequestQueue.add(newRequest);
mInFlightRequests.put(cacheKey,
        new BatchedImageRequest(newRequest, imageContainer));
    return imageContainer;
}
```

Hope it helps you !